# Using SSH.net in C# to get file content from a remote file

Tags: c#, ssh, copy, mysql, ssh.net

I am using SSH.NET (Renci.SshNet) library to retrieve the contents of a SQL file, but it doesnt seem to handle large files as my computer crashed when i tried to use the following code on a 500MB file.

```
using (SshCommand command = client.CreateCommand("cat " + filename))
                                {
                                    filecontent = command.Execute();
                                    SaveFileDialog theDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
                                    theDialog.Title = "Backup - " + filename;
                                    theDialog.Filter = "SQL files|*.sql";
                                    theDialog.FileName = filename;
                                    if (theDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
                                    {
                                        File.WriteAllText(theDialog.FileName, filecontent);
                                    }

                                }
```

I then tried to use SFTP to get the file but for some reason i cannot reach the httpd.private folder so i am currently stuck when trying to copy large files.

How can i transfer large files using similar technique to my C# Application for saving? I believe that SFTP is a better solution but i cannot reach the folder the sql is generated.

The SQL file is generated through mysqldump command.

Thanks!

Comment: SFTP/SCP is the right answer.  Re-post on ServerFault with whatever is preventing you from using SFTP.

Comment: Hi Mitch. I managed to solve this. I had to iterate over the folders and check if the file is in the directory by comparing the file names, then open a stream and download the file using sftpClient.DownloadFile()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to implement the use of the SftpClient that is buildt into SSH.net and iterate over the folders using SftpClient.ListDirectory() and compare the filenames with the file i was looking for. I then opened a stream and downloaded the file using SftpClient.DownloadFile().